# Best way to validate uploaded Excel file data using PHPExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

What would be the most efficient way of checking data contained in arrays

I want to validate in the following ways:

1. if cell a and b are a string
2. if cell c and d are numbers
3. if cells are empty

Then how would it be best to catch errors and display them to the user?

I'm using codeigniter and the PHPExcel library

an example of where I'm currently at

```
    public function read_excel()            
    {
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $inputFileName = 'test.xlsx';
        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();


        //  Loop through each row of the worksheet
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){     //  Read a row of data into an array
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);

            $cella = strtoupper($rowData[0][0]);
            $cellb = strtoupper($rowData[0][1]);
            $cellc = $rowData[0][2];
            $celld = $rowData[0][3];
        }


    }
```

To Answer my own question i eventually went with the below

```
                if (!isset($rowData[0][0],$rowData[0][1],$rowData[0][2])) {

                echo "error cells a-c are required.";
            }



            for ($i=0; $i <$columns ; $i++) { 
                switch ($rowData[0][$i]) {
                    case (is_numeric($rowData[0][$i])):
                        filter_var($rowData[0][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                        echo $rowData[0][$i];
                        echo "</br>";
                        break;
                    case (is_string($rowData[0][$i])):
                        $rowData[0][$i] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/"," ",$rowData[0][$i]);
                        break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: add some testing, e.g. `if (!filter_var($cella, ...)) { $errror[] = "cellA isn't whatever..."; }`

Comment: if i have more than 4 cells lets say cells a-z what you recommend to keep it dry?

Comment: more loops, probably.